# How can I rewrite sql query with having count to sequelize query?

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I have this one SQL string query:

```
SELECT company_id, COUNT(company_id)
FROM core.non_ceased_companies_prod_unit
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING COUNT(company_id) > 1
```

The result is:

[image]

I want to have a sum of second column (which is "No column name") and count of rows (now it's 4)

So the result should be:

```
{
  companies: 4
  productions: 11 //(2+3+2+4)
}
```

Query should be in Sequelize variant

Comment: You can name the column to e.g. "frequency" via: `COUNT(company_id) AS frequency`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm first day with Sequelize and SQL so I don't know how to rewrite it to Sequelize query. But this information is helpful too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an SQL view, you can select from that view:

**Note:** The query and schema below can be executed [via SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58257a/1/0).

### Stored procudure

```sql
CALL companyProductions();
```

### Result

| companies | productions |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 11 |

#### Sequalize

```js
sequelize
  .query('CALL companyProductions()')
  .then(data => console.log(data)); // [{ companies: 4, productions: 11 }]
```

#### Schema

Using delimiter: `//`

```sql
CREATE TABLE company (
  id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)//

CREATE TABLE non_ceased_companies_prod_unit (
  company_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  units int,
  CONSTRAINT FK_CompanyId FOREIGN KEY (company_id)
  REFERENCES company(id)
)//

CREATE VIEW unit_frequency_by_company AS
  SELECT company_id, COUNT(company_id) AS frequency
    FROM non_ceased_companies_prod_unit
    GROUP BY company_id
    HAVING frequency > 1//

CREATE PROCEDURE companyProductions()
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS companies, SUM(frequency) AS productions
    FROM unit_frequency_by_company;
END//
```

#### Schema data

```sql
INSERT INTO company(id, name)
  VALUES ('DK-10001560', 'Company A'),
         ('DK-10001587', 'Company B'),
         ('DK-10005809', 'Company C'),
         ('DK-10006511', 'Company D')//
 
INSERT INTO non_ceased_companies_prod_unit(company_id, units)
  VALUES ('DK-10001560', 1),
         ('DK-10001560', 1),
         ('DK-10001587', 1),
         ('DK-10001587', 1),
         ('DK-10001587', 1),
         ('DK-10005809', 1),
         ('DK-10005809', 1),
         ('DK-10006511', 1),
         ('DK-10006511', 1),
         ('DK-10006511', 1),
         ('DK-10006511', 1)//
```

Comment: Thank you! I need Sequelize query (using orm)

Comment: @VyacheslavTarshevskiy check-out the update response above.

Answer (score 2):

Please try following query :

```
SELECT COUNT(company_id) as companies, SUM(company_cnt) as productions FROM (
SELECT company_id, COUNT(company_id) as company_cnt
FROM core.non_ceased_companies_prod_unit
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING COUNT(company_id) > 1
)foo
```

Comment: Thank you. I've issues to write it in Sequelize query :(